# /bin/sh shell not execute when performing ret2libc attack

Tags: gdb

I have attempted to do a ret2libc attack. It's a simple buffer overflow with the return address pointed to the system call with the string "/bin/sh" on the stack. For some reason, when I try to execute the program, although the program perform a system call with string "/bin/sh", but no shell was spawned, and I'm not sure why that is the case. Below snapshots of the stack before and after entering system call.[image: stack information]

<sup>*The stack before entering system call. (From left to right) red underlines emphasize the address of the system call, the address of the exit() function call, and the address to the string "/bin/sh". Note: the ebp (starts at 0xbffff7b8) had been overwritten with junk data.*</sup>

Here is what happen after I attempted to step through each instructions and reach the end. I try to type in id, and whoami, but nothing happen.[image: shell not spawning]

Comment: Maybe try sharing a bit more info? What's your exploit and what exactly does the program do?

Comment: Hi Pawel, I'm attempting to do a ret2libc and spawn a shell. As for a program, it just declare a buffer of 64 bytes and call gets() to fill that buffer. I want to overwrite the return address with the system call and string "/bin/sh" as an input to spawn a shell with root privilege. You can find program source code in the following [link](https://exploit.education/protostar/stack-five/)